# What join should I use with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm working on a computing project and have been asked to use a join query to get information from two different tables. I want to get all the values from a single row in both tables. I'm using a unique id to identify each row.

```
if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
    $savingsId = $_GET['savingsId']; // To use to get other stuff
    $sql="SELECT Savings_Allocation.Bank,Savings_Allocation.TotalAmt,Savings_Allocation.Interest,Savings.Type,Savings.Access
          FROM Savings_Allocation,Savings
          INNER JOIN Savings
          WHERE Savings.savingsId AND Savings_Allocation.savingsId = '$savingsId'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

I've looked at existing examples but they seem and bit confusing/don't answer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code. Learn PDO or MySQLi and how to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few small mistakes in your query. In the 'From' section you only need to use the first table, and you'll need to tell the join which field from the first table matches which field in the second table. In the where you'll only have to match one field to `$savingsId`

This query should probably work:

```
SELECT Savings_Allocation.Bank,Savings_Allocation.TotalAmt,Savings_Allocation.Interest,Savings.Type,Savings.Access
FROM Savings_Allocation
INNER JOIN Savings ON Savings.savingsId = Savings_Allocation.savingsId
WHERE Savings.savingsId = '$savingsId'
```

Now the query above has one last flaw: using a variable inside a query string is unsafe and makes the query prone to SQL injection. So please read [PHP's guide on SQL injection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) on how to make a safe query. And don't use `mysql_query` as it's deprecated since php 5.5 and even removed in PHP 7. It's recommeded to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all possible queries on the two tables, students and payment.

```
students  name        id  id_student datepayment
1         Lisa         1    1        2017-01-01
2                      2    1        2017-02-03
3         Asher        3    2        2017-03-05
4         Lee          4    1        2017-03-03
```

The query

```
select students.name, payment.datepayment
FROM students, payment
where students.id_student = payment.id_student;
```

will give this result - all student's names which have id_student in table payment

```
name    datepayment
Lisa    2017-01-01
Lisa    2017-02-03
Lisa    2017-03-03
        2017-03-05
```

The query

```
SELECT s.name, p.datepayment
FROM
students s
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment p ON s.id_student = p.id_student;
```

will give this result: all students names from the LEFT table (students) which has or has not id_student in table payment:

```
name    datepayment
Lisa    2017-01-01
Lisa    2017-02-03
        2017-03-05
Lisa    2017-03-03
Asher       NULL
Lee         NULL
```

The query

```
SELECT s.name, p.datepayment
FROM
students s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN payment p ON s.id_student = p.id_student;
```

will give this result - all from RIGHT table payment and only students names which have id_student in table payment:

```
name    datepayment
Lisa    2017-01-01
Lisa    2017-02-03
        2017-03-05
Lisa    2017-03-03
```

The query

```
SELECT s.name, p.datepayment
FROM
students s
INNER JOIN payment p ON s.id_student = p.id_student;
```

will give this result - all students names which have id_student in table payment:

```
name    datepayment
Lisa    2017-01-01
Lisa    2017-02-03
Lisa    2017-03-03
        2017-03-05
```